# Changing a property right after removing observers still sends out a KVO Notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, objective-c-runtime

I have some scenarios where a property is changing, but I do not want to notify observers of the change.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
  [self.fontColorWell removeObserver:self.toolController forKeyPath:@"color"];
  [self.fontColorWell setColor:[self.toolController valueForKey:[self fontColorKeyPath]]];
```

Unfortunately, when the second line executes, the observer (`self.toolController`) on `self.fontColorWell` still gets notified.

I'm pretty sure I know why this is happening, because `KVO` works by the runtime subclassing the observed class, and overridding the observed property to add `didChange` and `willChange` messages. (https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html)

If I set a breakpoint at the second line, I can see clearly the class type of self.fontColorWell: `NSKVONotifying_NSColorWell`.  So when `-setColor` is called, it's still called on the runtime subclass, which has the overridden setter that notifies observers.

But I figured that because I called `removeObserver` right before, shouldn't the observer be removed from the KVO lookup table, and thus even though the KVO object notifies observers, my `self.toolController` shouldn't be notified?

I know 100% that when `-setColor` is called, `self.toolController` immediately receives the `-observeValueForKeyPath...` message.  I also am positive that all of there are no extra instances of my objects hanging around

Am I just not allowed to do what I'm trying to do?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `fontColorKeyPath` is `@"color"`? The `observeValueForKeyPath...` is for that key? `toolController` isn't observing another key?

Comment: Yup good questions, made me realize this is a super silly problem.  There was a subclass who didn't override the method with this code, and that subclass returned a different value for `fontColorKeyPath`.  Identified that the reasoning behind that was redundant legacy, so I made it so all subclasses returned the same keypath and it worked